# Area reduction factor reference for precipitation

Tags: hydrology, precipitation, rainfall

For a large catchment (>1000ha) I'm looking for some method to use a area reduction factor to adapt precipitation values. I have a large dataset of daily precipitation values but I have to use some kind of adaptation. I have don't enough data to calibrate a rainfall runoff model.

I have looked in some literature but there is little generally usable information. Does someone has a good reference for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether your data is from a single gauge or a network of gauges, and whether you have storm tracking data or not. Sounds to me like you have daily precip at a single gauge without much more information. If you know the annual average precipitation in the basin then a simple area reduction factor (ARF) calculation is basically the ratio of the annual average gauge precipitation over the basin average.

I am not too familiar with the literature on this, but this [report](https://d2dtl5nnlpfr0r.cloudfront.net/tti.tamu.edu/documents/0-4642-3.pdf) seems like a good starting point for background info.

Comment: I have daily precip at a single gauge indeed. Thanks for the report!